# Load text file content using jQuery dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to load the text file data on html page dynamically.

I have written script which loads data on button click.

here is my html

```
<div class="text">
    Default Data <br />
</div>

<div class="button">
    <input type="button" id="click" value="Click!" />
</div>
```

and my script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "demo.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Now I need to update the data when text file content changed without click.

any work around.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to catch file change event. But many workarounds are possible. Like `setInterval()`

Comment: @Shaunak D: Never a good comment. Always likely to be proved wrong. My own motto is "everything is possible, but it may cost you more" :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, elaborated a little. My first reaction was the solution is not possible, added it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. What only you can do is refresh the content every certain time.

```
$("#click").click(function() {
  setTimeInterval(function() {
     $(".text").load('demo.txt');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: How twitter and facebook achieve this without reloading page?

Comment: @OpenCurious: those sites use 2-way communication with the browser and notify changes. Check out Signal-R for starters.

Comment: You can do it with long polling using php and ajax or with node.js or other server like that. The logic is roughly to make several different query to the txt and update the div if the content has changed.

Comment: @LelioFaieta thanks for comment. do you have any work around using node.js, link will be appreciable.

Comment: These are two links to projects, close to your need created using node. One uses file to load contents the other uses a database. These are just two small example I used as inspiration to start with to deal with node.js myself: [link]http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/[/link] and [link]http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/[/link]