# Having issue with the load() event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello I'm new to javascript and facing a problem that I cant find a solution of.
I am trying to create an one page website.
I'm not saying that the web will only contain a single page.The web will contain multiple pages but when we will click on the buttons that are in the nav section the web won't get loaded.Rather than getting loaded, it will just load a txt file by the event called load().
The txt file contains some html elements.And the elements has a button. Whenever the button is clicked a div element will show up.
For showing up a div element I have included a js file into my html file.
But all the function in that file is not working to show the div when btn is clicked.
Here is the html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/body.css"/>
    
    <title>INDIEDEV</title>
    
</head>

<body>

<nav class="nav">
  <button class="nav-item Ihome">HOME</button>
  <button class="nav-item Iportfolio">PORTFOLIO</button>
  <button class="nav-item Iservices">SERVICES</button>
  <button class="nav-item Ihire">HIRE</button>
  <div class="nav-indicator"></div>
</nav>

<div class="page">
  
 <div class="greeth">
    <h1 class="greeth-h1">
      HELLO
    <br/>
      I'M 
    <span>Y</span>
      EAMIN
    <p class="p1h">AND THIS IS MY PERSONAL WEBSITE</p>
    <p class="p2h">ENJOY YOUR VIEW, SIR.</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="imageh">
    <img src="../images/Dq6yj5QXQAAmLOQ.jpeg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="abouth">
    <h4 class="abouth-h1">
    ABOUT
    </h4>
    <div class="abouth-p">
    <p class="abouth-p1">
    Hello sir,
    <br />
    I'm Yeamin and I really love to put my hands on the keyboard
    <br />
    feel safe to offer me any project related to my skills and before that pls checkout my buyer reviews
    <br />
    My work is neet and clean and your satisfaction is my first priority
    </p>
    <p class="abouth-p2">
      Lives in Bangladesh
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="skillsh">
    <h4 class="skillsh-h1">
      SKILLS
    </h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="servicesh">
    <h4 class="servicesh-h1">
      SERVICES
    </h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="reviewsh">
    <h4 class="reviewsh-h1">
      BUYER REVIEWS
    </h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
      <p>FOOTER</p>
      <div class="credit">Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com></a></div>
    </div>
 
</div>


<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader-box"></div>
</div>

<div class="preloader">
  <div class="stick1"></div>
  <div class="stick2"></div>
</div>


<script src="../js/nav.js"></script>
<script src="../js/page.js"></script>
<script src="../js/preloader.js"></script>
<script src="../js/services.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

In here there is a navbar and four btns for each page.I havn't put any links to the pages behind the btns because I want something linke when a specific btn is clecked a txt file carrying some html elements will get loaded into the div element which is having a class called 'page' by the help of js load() event and I have included a js file called page.js (you can see it in the bottom of the html body) for that.
Here it is
(Just checkout the $('page').load('specific txt file'))

```
var Hbtn = document.querySelector('.Ihome')
var pbtn = document.querySelector('.Iportfolio')
var sbtn = document.querySelector('.Iservices')
var hbtn = document.querySelector('.Ihire')
var loader = document.querySelector('.loader')
var loaderBox = document.querySelector('.loader-box')

Hbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  loader.style.animation = 'loader 4s'
  Hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  pbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  sbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.add('loaderBox')
    $('.page').load('home.txt')
  },1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.remove('loaderBox')
    loader.style.animation = 'none'
    Hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    pbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    sbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }, 4000)
  })

pbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  loader.style.animation = 'loader 4s'
  Hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  pbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  sbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')

  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.add('loaderBox')
    $('.page').load('portfolio.txt')
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.remove('loaderBox')
    loader.style.animation = 'none'
    Hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    pbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    sbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }, 4000)
})

sbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  loader.style.animation = 'loader 4s'
  Hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  pbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  sbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')

  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.add('loaderBox')
    $('.page').load('services.txt')
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.remove('loaderBox')
    loader.style.animation = 'none'
    Hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    pbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    sbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }, 4000)
})

hbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  loader.style.animation = 'loader 4s'
  Hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  pbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  sbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  hbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')

  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.add('loaderBox')
    $('.page').load('hire.txt')
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
    loaderBox.classList.remove('loaderBox')
    loader.style.animation = 'none'
    Hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    pbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    sbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    hbtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }, 4000)
});
```

In here var(sbtn) is the btn for services page in the navbar.So whenever it is clicked, a txt file called services.txt will get loaded into the (page div).it works all well  and no problem in this.
But the problem is I have some functions for services.txt. I know that no function will work on txt files. But what I'm trying to say is when I will click the btn in the navbar to get services.txt file to get loaded into the (div page), all the element structure that are inside of that txt file will convert into an html element, isn't it? SO the js file (services.js) that I have included to add some functions for the elements inside of the txt file will work.

But the problem is it doesn't work

Here is the services.txt and services.js file

```
<div class="serviceS-box">
  <div class="serviceS-card">
    <li class="liS-img"><img class="serviceS-logo" src="../images/001-small-notepad-and-pencil-outlines.png"/></li>
    <li class="liS-title"><p class="serviceS-title">COPY WRITING</p></li>
    <li class="liS-info"><p class="serviceS-info"></p></li>
    <li class="liS-btn">
    <button class="liS-btnI liS-btn-more">MORE</button>
    <button class="liS-btnI liS-btn-hire">HIRE</button>
    </li>
    <div class="liS-more-info-blur">
      <ul class="liS-more-info-box">
        <li class="more-info">
          <p class="more-infoI">
            hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="more-info-stick"><div class="more-info-stickI"></div></li>
        <li class="more-info-btn-close">
          <button class="more-info-btn-closeI liS-btnI">CLOSE</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="serviceS-card">
    <li class="liS-img"><img class="serviceS-logo" src="../images/002-open-book-with-silhouette.png"/></li>
    <li class="liS-title"><p class="serviceS-title">CONTENT WRITING</p></li>
    <li class="liS-info"><p class="serviceS-info"></p></li>
    <li class="liS-btn">
      <button class="liS-btnI liS-btn-more">MORE</button>
      <button class="liS-btnI liS-btn-hire">HIRE</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  
  <div class="serviceS-card">
    <li class="liS-img"><img class="serviceS-logo" src="../images/003-coding.png"/></li>
    <li class="liS-title"><p class="serviceS-title">CODING</p></li>
    <li class="liS-info"><p class="serviceS-info"></p></li>
    <li class="liS-btn">
      <button class="liS-btnI liS-btn-more">MORE</button>
      <button class="liS-btnI liS-btn-hire">HIRE</button>
    </li>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```
var btnMore = document.getElementsByClassName('liS-btn-more')
var btnMoreCL = document.getElementsByClassName('more-info-btn-closeI')

for (var i = 0; i < btnMore.length; i++) {
  var btnMoreC = btnMore[i]
  btnMoreC.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var btnMoreClicked = event.target;
    btnMoreClicked.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].classList.add('blur')
    btnMoreClicked.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].classList.add('box')
  })
}

for (var j = 0; j < btnMoreCL.length; j++) {
  var btnMoreCc = btnMoreCL[j]
  btnMoreCc.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var btnMoreCLClicked = event.target;
    btnMoreCLClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('blur')
    btnMoreCLClicked.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('box')
  })
}
```

Functions inside of the js file has no problem and I have tested them.
In my opinion the problem is when the txt file get loaded into the html it actually actually doesn't save them into the html file it just loads them.
So the variables inside of my js file can't actually find the elements inside the dom.
But someone pls help me on how I can make the whole thing work.

Comment: instead of .txt file try loading as actual .html file. I guess that might resolve it.

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827998/load-text-file-content-using-jquery-dynamically

Comment: Yah kinda similar and I will try it.